# Mysql: Order joined table

Tags: mysql

```
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_id) AS `i` ON i.ad_id = a.id
```

How to order joined table without using temporary table? :)

Because it's 5x slower than simple join:

```
RIGHT JOIN images AS `i` ON i.ad_id = a.id
```

And there are problems with fields list, which should be duplicated inside subquery as well to avoid using * sign.

Thanks ;)

**Update**

```
SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(image_id) AS `image_ids`
FROM `ads` AS `a`
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_id) AS `i` ON i.ad_id = a.id
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`id` DESC
```

There are multiple rows that match per id in joined table. That's why i need to order them.

```
group_concat(image_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by image_id after the join.

(You do have an index on image_id, don't you?)

**UPDATE:**

You can put the `ORDER BY` inside your `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(image_id ORDER BY image_id)
```

and then you don't need the subquery.

Comment: :) not a solution. Order should be used for different table field.

Comment: Sure, it's primary key and ad_id as well have index.

Comment: Cool! I didn't knew that! Thanks mate. +1 :)

Comment: Glad to help.  And I just gained a new privilege... yay!

Comment: Rofl :D Baaaah! Solution is working, but I just noticed it doesn't order the rest GROUP_CONCAT fields. I need to use it in each field. Ok ty anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear in this example *why* you need to order the subquery, so I'd say just get rid of the ordering frmo the subquery and only apply ordering on the outermost query.

Comment: because of group_concat(i.image_id) :) There a multiple rows inside joined table

Comment: @Beck: Then maybe you should post the whole query.

Comment: Sure sorry, it's my laziness and bad habit. Just a moment.

Comment: @Beck: I don't have MySQL here to test with but have you tried adding a third outer query that *just* does the group_concat and ordering on the result of your current outer query (minus the grouping and ordering of course)?

Comment: Please add an example of modified query and i'll launch it here. :)

Comment: @Beck: No. Stop being lazy! :P